# Elasticsearch Term Filter Slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, elasticsearch, tire

We're running a 2 node elasticsearch cluster with 2 indexes currently and it's performing beautifully (750k docs and 11.1 million docs).

We're now trying to add a new index with 35.4 million docs and the search performance is slow.  A term filter takes about 2 seconds to return.

Mapping:

```
tire do
  mapping _routing: { required: true, path: :order_id } do
    indexes :id,            type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :order_id,      type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed

    [:first_name, :last_name, :company_name, :title, :email, :city, :state_region_province, :postal_code].each do |attribute|
      indexes attribute, type: 'string', analyzer: 'keyword'
    end

    indexes :metadata,      type: 'string'
    indexes :clicks,        type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :view_count,    type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :sender,        type: 'boolean', index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :bounced,       type: 'boolean', index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :unsubscribed,  type: 'boolean', index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
  end
end
```

Searching:

```
Model.tire.search(load: true, page: page, per_page: per_page, routing: order_id) do |search|
  search.query do
    match :metadata, query, type: 'phrase_prefix', max_expansions: 10
  end if query.present?

  search.filter :term, order_id: order_id
  search.filter :term, sender: false
end
```

The search I'm doing is just specifying an order_id to filter on; it takes about 2 seconds to return results.  How do I speed this up?

**Edit:**
I'm now indexing the user_id and using it as the routing path.  I've created a new index with 30 shards to test overallocation.

**Edit 2:**
With 30 shards, the index is more performant but still takes over a second to return data on the first query.  I'm not sure how to speed this up more or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you toggle analyzing for the `order_id` field to `:keyword`? From:

```
indexes :order_id,      type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
```

to:

```
indexes :order_id,      type: 'string', index: :keyword
```

[The docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-analyzer.html) say:

> An analyzer of type keyword that “tokenizes” an entire stream as a single token. This is useful for data like zip codes, ids and so on.

It seems like that'd apply to an `order_id`.

Comment: I did 'not_analyzed' because the term filter specifically mentions using it: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-filter.html

Comment: Honestly for something like a numeric id I'm not sure what the difference would be between not_analyzed and keyword.  The keyword analyzer just spits out the entire input as a single token but in this case a numeric id is already a single token when not analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using facets with your query, I would suggest converting your query into [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query.html) and moving term filters from the top level to filters in the filtered query. See also [Performance of elastic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007078/performance-of-elastic-queries)

Comment: I'll give that a whirl and report back.

Comment: I've tried that without any difference.  Note that in my search, I'm not specifying a query string so this is just testing the 2 term filters.